# Depth or Grade of an ideal

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$$\subset$$ S$ be commutative noetherian rings,and $I$ is an ideal of $S$.
We now that $I$ is a $R-$module.
Do we have $grade_{R}(I)$ $\le$ $ grade_{S}(I)$?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "an ideal of $R$ and $S$"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that $R$ is a subring of $S$.

Comment: But it is very unlikely that an ideal in $R$ is also an ideal in $S$...

Comment: Yes, but you can take for example $I$ an ideal of $S$ and generated by elements in $R$.

Comment: I think that, if $R$ and $S$ are local, then we have the inequality.

Comment: Could you give me just one example where this situation occurs?

Comment: You mean for an ideal or for the inequality?

Comment: For an ideal of $R$ which is also an ideal of $S$.

Comment: Oh my god, I see the problem now(I'm stupid). But if we assume that $I$ is an ideal of $S$, and we look at $I$ as a $R-$module. Can we say something about the inequality above?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{grade}_I(R)$ when $I$ is a $R$-module? I think what is reasonable is to start with an ideal $I$ of $R$ and consider $\mathrm{grade}_{S}(IS)$. Then this is indeed $\geq \mathrm{grade}_{R}(I)$ if $S$ is flat over $R$.

Comment: grade of $I$ as $R-$module is the smaller numbre $n$ such that $Ext_{R}^{n}(I,R) \ne 0$

Comment: @user26857 , we have two definitions of $grade(I)$. For example, if we see $I$ like an ideal then the grade is the number of the maximal regular sequence of $R$ in $I$.

Comment: @user26857 thanks for the reference. I have another question. If we assume that $R$ and $S$ are graded, do we have equality of depth?

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake.

Comment: @user26857, see definition 1.2.11 in Bruns and Herzog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is  false. Take any $R$-module $M$ of grade $>0$, and put $S=R\oplus M$,  the product of any two elements of $M$  being $0$. Then $M$ is an ideal of $S$ and $\mathrm{grade}_S(M)=0\ $ (because $\mathrm{Hom}_S(S/M,S)\neq 0$).